# AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'Future'

Tags: tornado, python-3.7

Im running into an issue where I'm running Python 3.7.7, and installed asyncio using

`pip3 install asyncio`

However, when I run this in the terminal:

`python3`

`import asyncio`

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        from .base_events import *
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 23, in <module>
        import socket
      File "/Users/me/socket.py", line 1, in <module>
        import tornado.ioloop
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 45, in <module>
        from tornado.concurrent import (
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 47, in <module>
        Future = asyncio.Future
    AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'Future'
```

I can most definitely see that `asyncio` has the Futures attribute. Not sure why its giving me this exception. Any thoughts on what it could be?

Comment: "The asyncio module is part of the Python standard library since Python 3.4", you did not need install it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've created a file `socket.py` which is shadowing the standard library's `socket` module. You must avoid using any module names which collide with modules from the standard library.